# macOS Sierra frequent internal error

Tags: macos, error

After upgrading to macOS Sierra (version 10.12), I frequently get the following error when using different applications like Adobe Acrobat, XtraFinder, Microsoft Office, etc. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

**Internal Error**

An uncaught exception was raised...

```
Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: -[AVCocoaMenuItem accessibilityIsAttributeSettable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b7c3f40
User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x9467521b __raiseError + 187
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9ed086e6 objc_exception_throw + 273
2   CoreFoundation                      0x946790bc -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 172
3   CoreFoundation                      0x9455c835 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x9455c41e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   AppKit                              0x92b34979 __NSAccessibilityEntryPointIsAttributeSettable_block_invoke + 220
6   AppKit                              0x92b340b5 NSAccessibilityPerformEntryPointBOOL + 141
7   AppKit                              0x929169d4 NSAccessibilityEntryPointIsAttributeSettable + 98
8   AppKit                              0x929577dd -[NSObject(NSAccessibilityInternal) _accessibilityCanSetValueForAttribute:clientError:] + 204
9   AppKit                              0x929d9271 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonIsAccessibleAttributeSettableEvent:handlerCallRef:axElement:] + 175
10  AppKit                              0x926fa042 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 1163
11  HIToolbox                           0x93c9afce _Z22_InvokeEventHandlerUPPP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPvPFlS0_S2_S3_E + 26
12  HIToolbox                           0x93c46f42 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 2013
13  HIToolbox                           0x93c460b8 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 419
14  HIToolbox                           0x93c45f07 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 40
15  HIToolbox                           0x93cd9602 _ZN10Accessible24IsNamedAttributeSettableEPK10__CFStringPh + 130
16  HIToolbox                           0x93cd953e HLTBIsUIElementAttributeSettable + 48
17  HIToolbox                           0x93cdba9a _ZL33CarbonIsAttributeSettableCallbackPK8__CFDatamPK10__CFStringPPK11__CFBooleanPv + 94
18  AppKit                              0x9295af9f IsAttributeSettable + 361
19  HIServices                          0x9359aeac _AXXMIGIsAttributeSettable + 260
20  HIServices                          0x935a4a11 _XIsAttributeSettable + 412
21  HIServices                          0x93579adb mshMIGPerform + 202
22  CoreFoundation                      0x94568c95 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
23  CoreFoundation                      0x94568bf5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 533
24  CoreFoundation                      0x94560d59 __CFRunLoopRun + 2553
25  CoreFoundation                      0x945600fa CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 506
26  CoreFoundation                      0x9455feeb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
27  HIToolbox                           0x93c681c2 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 268
28  HIToolbox                           0x93c67fae ReceiveNextEventCommon + 494
29  HIToolbox                           0x93c67da7 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 83
30  AppKit                              0x9257848f _DPSNextEvent + 1193
31  AppKit                              0x92c76ce9 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1423
32  AppKit                              0x92c76752 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 132
33  AppKit                              0x92c77fd4 _NSHLTBMenuEventProc + 198
34  HIToolbox                           0x93cba8af _ZL19IsUserStillTrackingP14MenuSelectDataPh + 349
35  HIToolbox                           0x93e307dd _ZL15TrackMenuCommonR14MenuSelectDataPhP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS5_ + 1651
36  HIToolbox                           0x93e2c2b0 _ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjPK4RecttmS4_S4_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 1885
37  HIToolbox                           0x93e2b703 _ZL26_HandlePopUpMenuSelection8P13OpaqueMenuRefP14OpaqueEventRefm5PointtjPK4RecttS6_S6_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPS0_Pt + 851
38  HIToolbox                           0x93ca8253 _HandlePopUpMenuSelectionWithDictionary + 263
39  AppKit                              0x9282e089 _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 6303
40  AppKit                              0x92934dd8 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 193
41  AppKit                              0x92934c73 -[NSMenu _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 234
42  AppKit                              0x92934b84 -[NSMenu _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:] + 40
43  AppKit                              0x92b4aecf +[NSMenu popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:] + 37
44  Acrobat                             0x004b7ea9 RunAcrobat + 3285049
45  Acrobat                             0x004b91e1 RunAcrobat + 3289969
46  Acrobat                             0x0094d510 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 4315938
47  Acrobat                             0x0094d5de AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 4316144
48  Acrobat                             0x00862035 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3352135
49  Acrobat                             0x006a56f0 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 1531138
50  Acrobat                             0x006a5ec0 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 1533138
51  Acrobat                             0x0079bdea AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 2540540
52  Acrobat                             0x0079b2eb AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 2537725
53  Acrobat                             0x0079b375 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 2537863
54  Acrobat                             0x00862578 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3353482
55  Acrobat                             0x00862289 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3352731
56  Acrobat                             0x0086fede AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3409136
57  Acrobat                             0x0086fd6d AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3408767
58  Acrobat                             0x00a134f2 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 5126916
59  Acrobat                             0x00a0fc3f AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 5112401
60  AppKit                              0x92dd0e33 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5876
61  AppKit                              0x92dcf3c1 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 547
62  AppKit                              0x92c756de -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 2854
63  AppKit                              0x9256d1c5 -[NSApplication run] + 1018
64  Acrobat                             0x00197826 RunAcrobat + 6582
65  Acrobat                             0x00195fa3 RunAcrobat + 307
66  AdobeAcrobat                        0x0003ded5 main + 91
67  AdobeAcrobat                        0x0003de71 start + 53
68  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same problem, turned out to be an incompatible Accessiblity extension, e.g. go into Preferences, Security & Privacy > Accessiblity section.
Most likely there is an extension which causes the issue.

I disabled all of them and removed unnecessary ones (e.g. Dropbox).

Comment: Bunch of apps were bombing out after update to Sierra and this fixed them all

Answer (score 1):

FTR, "repair permissions" is not even possible in Sierra, and really did next to nothing in most instances in older versions of the OS X, other than make people feel good.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

1st thing I would do for repetitive problem like this is to repair permissions:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560

Especially as in your case where you upgrade to Sierra (and not install Sierra on a fresh partition)

Comment: Clean install of Sierra not solve the problem. A workaround is to disable the extensions as described by @Peter R.